# Struts - My action is called twice

Tags: java, struts

I'm using jsp include like this:

```
<jsp:include page="/citybest.html">
    <jsp:param value="shopping" name="action"/>
</jsp:include>
```

This calls a method 'shopping' method of my action class. But my problem is that this method is called twice. If I remove this include call it is not called at all. I checked in the debug mode of ecilipse. Do any one have any idea on what's the case here?

Comment: There are two hit to this page I guess try checking some thing is also trying to GET this

Comment: I'm using decorators and filters also. Is is possible due to them. Also when I start my resin it initializes 'WebApplicationContext for struts' twice. Could it be due to this?

Answer (score 3):

if you have a form where the submit button also calls a method that includes form.submit() then this will cause the form to be submitted twice in some browsers. Otherwise you'll need to provide more information.